# Embedding Riemmanian Manifold Linearly

Tags: riemannian-geometry, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-manifold, hilbert-manifolds

Given a Hilbert Manifold $M$ does there exist a smooth map into some very large Hilbert space taking geodesics to straight lines?

Comment: If $M = S^1$ you have to map all of $M$ into a single line, so you won't have an embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, for example let $M$ be such that there exists a compact geodesic $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow M$ (for example $M=S^n$).  n this case if such a map $\phi:S^n\rightarrow V$ did exist (where $V$ is a linear space) then $\phi\circ\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow V$ must also be compact, however a line in $V$ is not compact; a contraction.

Comment: Hence it is not possible for any closed finite dimensional manifold, as they always carry a closed geodesic.

Comment: Reading this, I am wondering another related question: does there exist a (Nash-type) isometric embedding theorem for Hilbert manifolds in its model Hilbert space? There are some works of the '60s building $C^{\infty}$ embeddings, but my guess is that there does not exist such an object. Have you ever hear of something related?